# SQL WHERE Clause Execution Order

Tags: where-clause, sql-execution-plan

How is the execution of the WHERE clause in a SQL statement determined?

For example:

This first query executes in 8 seconds.

```
SELECT c.claimnum, 
       cd.procedurecode, 
       cd.charges, 
       cd.contractamount, 
       dbo.Fn_getfeeschedamount(cd.pk_claimdetail) 
FROM   claim c WITH(nolock) 
       INNER JOIN claimdetail cd WITH(nolock) 
               ON cd.fk_claim = c.pk_claim 
WHERE  c.dateprocessed BETWEEN dbo.Fn_datenotime(Getdate()) AND Replace( 
                                      Cast(dbo.Fn_datenotime(Getdate()) AS 
                                           VARCHAR), '12:00AM', '11:59PM') 
ORDER  BY c.claimnum
```

This second query executes in 10 seconds.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT c.claimnum, 
               cd.procedurecode, 
               cd.charges, 
               cd.contractamount, 
               dbo.Fn_getfeeschedamount(cd.pk_claimdetail) AS [CalcAmount] 
        FROM   claim c WITH(nolock) 
               INNER JOIN claimdetail cd WITH(nolock) 
                       ON cd.fk_claim = c.pk_claim 
        WHERE  c.dateprocessed BETWEEN dbo.Fn_datenotime(Getdate()) AND Replace( 
                                               Cast(dbo.Fn_datenotime(Getdate()) 
                                                    AS 
                                                    VARCHAR), '12:00AM', 
                                       '11:59PM')) AS 
       c1 
WHERE  c1.contractamount <> c1.[calcamount] 
ORDER  BY c1.claimnum
```

This third query takes much longer to execute (I didn't wait to see how long; over 4 minutes).

```
SELECT c.claimnum, 
       cd.procedurecode, 
       cd.charges, 
       cd.contractamount, 
       dbo.Fn_getfeeschedamount(cd.pk_claimdetail) 
FROM   claim c WITH(nolock) 
       INNER JOIN claimdetail cd WITH(nolock) 
               ON cd.fk_claim = c.pk_claim 
WHERE  c.dateprocessed BETWEEN dbo.Fn_datenotime(Getdate()) AND Replace( 
                                      Cast(dbo.Fn_datenotime(Getdate()) AS 
                                           VARCHAR), '12:00AM', '11:59PM') 
       AND cd.contractamount <> dbo.Fn_getfeeschedamount(cd.pk_claimdetail) 
ORDER  BY c.claimnum
```

I am running this on a SQL Server 2016 database.

The first query shows all claims for today with their processed amounts and their recalculated amounts.

The last query was my goal of adding one more condition to my where clause to only show claims where the recalculated amount does not match the amount calculated at processing time.

It appears that in the last query, SQL Server is executing the second part of the where clause before the first causing the query to run much longer.

Is there a way to force SQL Server to execute the first part of the where clause first without having to resort to the second query?

Comment: It would probably help a lot if you formatted your code in a clean manner so that others can read it easily. The easier your problem is to read, the more likely you are to get someone to come help you.

Comment: I would but I am not familiar enough with this editor to put in line breaks without forcing double spacing.

Comment: Edited your question with appropriate formatting.

Comment: Is there no way to control the order of the execution of the conditions in the where clause?